# About polynomial calculus on symmetric/non-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-calculus

If $A$ is real symmetric matrix then there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that

$$ A = QDQ^T$$

Then, if $f$ is a polynomial, one can write

\begin{equation}
f(A)=Qf(D)Q^T
\end{equation}

and also
$$\|f(A)\| = max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}|f(\lambda)|$$

where the last equation follows from the fact that $A$ is a symmetric matrix and hence $\rho(A) = \|A\|$

$\textbf{First Question}:$ To find out the third equation from the fact that $f(A) = Qf(D)Q^T$ , so $\|f(A)\| = \|Qf(D)Q^T\|$ is enought o say that an orthogonal matrix doesn't affect the norm and therefore $$\|Qf(D)Q^T\| = \|f(D)\|?$$

$\textbf{Second Question}:$ What if A is not symmetric but still diagonalizable, so

$$A = PDP^{-1}$$

with $P$ a matrix of eigenvectors, then for any polynomial I can still write

$$f(A) = Pf(A)P^{-1}$$

,but what can I say about $\|f(A)\|$? Only that, in general

$$\|f(A)\| \ge \rho(A)?$$

Answer (score 1):

First Question : The frobenius norm of $f(A)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\|f(A)\|_F^2 &= \sup_{x} \frac{\|f(A) x\|^2_2}{\|x\|_x^2}\\
&= \sup_x \frac{x^T Q f(D)^T f(D) Q^T x}{x^T x}\\
&= \sup_y \frac{y^T f(D)^T f(D) y}{y^T Q^T Q y}\\
&= \sup_y \frac{\|f(D) y\|^2}{\|y\|^2}\\
&= \|f(D)\|_F^2
\end{align*}

Second Question : The above result is true for any square matrix $A$, you can prove it using the [Jordan Normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), in this case $D$ is a Jordan matrix and then $\|f(A)\|_F = \|f(D)\| \geq \max_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)} |f(\lambda)|$. In general it is not true that $\|f(A)\|_f\geq \rho(A)$, imagine if $f(B)=0$ for all $B$ and $A$ is positive definite.

Observe that your first result also holds for any $C^\infty$ function, not only polynomials, since a $C^\infty$ is an infinite polynomial (Taylor development).

Comment: So you're saying that if $A$ is not symmetric but diagonalizable ($A= PDP^{-1}$) then $\|A\|$ = $\|D\|$ with $D$ diagonal matrix? But now I would think that for any matrix( even non symmetric) one could end up with $\rho(A) = \|A\|$ How is this possible?(considering $f$ as the identity)Sorry I'm just a little bit confused..

Comment: Of course if $D$ is diagonal then $\|f(A)\|_F=\max_{\lambda} f(\lambda)$. The thing is when you pass through $f$, you cannot give a bound. So $\|f(A)\|_f = \rho(f(A))$ but there is no relation in general to $\rho(A)$

Comment: but you are supposing $f(A)$ symmetric to write $\|f(A)\| = \rho((f(A))$  .. is this true?

Comment: Actually no it is not, but in the end it doesn't change the point that there is not general relation between $\|f(A)\|_F$ and $\rho(A)$